# Packaging a python project which requires non-python packages

Tags: python, packages

I'm following the python documentation about ["distributing packages using setuptools"](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/). It doesn't mention what to do if a python package you want to include in your [`install_requires`](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#install-requires) requires a system installation. For example:

I'd like to include the package [pysoundfile](https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io), but this requires me to install `libsndfile1` via my system package manager, e.g. `sudo apt-get install libsndfile1`.

I've got as far as understanding I need to make a **binary distribution**, given advice in the docs [here](https://packaging.python.org/overview/#python-source-distributions), but that sends me to the docs listed above.

How do I automate this process such that users of my package can simply `pip install my_package` and not have to `apt-get install libsndfile1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL/DR;** Use Python's [distutils](https://docs.python.org/3/library/distutils.html) module in `setup.py` in order to bundle `libsndfile` together with your application in a single binary Wheel.

Python packages can come as source distributions or as binary distributions (Python Wheels, `.whl`). When a package requiring a native library (e.g. `libsndfile`) is installed from source, the installing system needs to have the native library installed and a corresponding toolchain (e.g. gcc) to link the Python package with the native library.

To avoid the need for a compile toolchain and for `apt-get install …`, you can use Python's distutils module. Especially `distutils.build_clib` is what you are looking for. This allows you to build `libsndfile` as a static library inside `setup.py` and bundle it into a Python Wheel together with your application. You might want to have look at other projects that use this method, such as [argon2_cffi](https://github.com/hynek/argon2-cffi/blob/46e54907ddce286a6030ca3b039b792403b8f026/setup.py).

Note that bundling native dependencies together with your Python application has drawbacks as well:

- Since the native libraries are statically linked, users of your application will not get any security updates when they update their OS version of `libsndfile`. You have to take care of that.
- Python Wheels are specific to a platform (i.e. combination of CPU architecture and OS). If you intend to support many different platforms, you need to build many different wheels. Take a look at the many wheels produced by the [Pillow project](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/#files)

Comment: This is incredibly helpful. Thank you.